# Multiple representation of child entity in parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm curious if it is possible to have several @ManyToOne relations of same entity in parent entity with JPA/Hibernate.

**Example:**
I have bank transactions, each transaction has a **BankPartner** in tow roles **Creditor** and **Debtor**.  The point is, I want to edit data only once. BankPartner with nickName "mistress" is only one :), doesn't matter if in role creditor or debtor. Once, it will be  renamed to wife, so I don't want to change separately. Also, the Balance is SUM of all transactions for BankPartner in both roles.

@Entity 
public class **Transaction** {
..

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true, targetEntity = PartnerEntity.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "CREDITOR_ID")
private **BankPartner** *creditor*

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = PartnerEntity.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEBTOR_ID")
private **BankPartner** *debtor*
..

}

@Entity
public class **BankPartner** {
...
private String name;
private String nickName;
private String description;
...
}

I can imagine that from "Transaction" direction in can somehow work, but can't find a way to work from BankPartner direction.

I can see two different approaches

1. create @ManyToMany with "ROLE_TYPE" in intersection table between BankPartner and Transaction
2. create two separate entities Debtor an Creditor from the same table.

But, as I said, I'm curios about the first approach ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a multi column join as such:

```java
@Entity
public class Transaction { 

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval=true, targetEntity = PartnerEntity.class)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEBTOR_ID"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "CREDITOR_ID")
})
private BankPartner partner

}
```